# Filling the list with responses and processing them at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, request, threadpool

I'm trying to download some products from a web page. This web page (according to robots.txt) allows me to send 2000req/minute. The problem is that sequential sending requests and then processing it is too much time-consuming.

I've realised that method which sends request can be moved into the pool which is much better according to time consume. It's probably because the processor don't need to wait to response and rather sends another request at the moment.

So I have a pool, the responses are being appended into the list RESPONSES.

Simple code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import requests

RESPONSES = []

with open('products.txt') as f:
    LINES = f.readlines()[:100]

def post_request(url):
    html = requests.get(url).content
    RESPONSES.append(html)

def parse_html_return_object(resp):
    #some code here
    pass

def insert_object_into_database():
    pass

pool = Pool(100)

for line in LINES:
    pool.apply_async(post_request,args=(line[:-1],))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The thing I want is to process those RESPONSES (HTMLS) so it would be popping responses from RESPONSE list and parsing it during the requesting.

So it could be like this (Time -->):

```
post_request(line1)->post_request(line2)->Response_line1->parse_html_return_object(response)->post_request...
```

Is there some simple way to do that?